# Error in processing request Error code: 500 Error text: Internal Server Error

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, permissions

I have migrated my WordPress site to a new host. I have done everything. Now I am getting this error:

> "Error in processing request Error code: 500 Error text: Internal
>   Server Error" while trying to access phpmyadmin.

[image]

Comment: A 500 Internal Server error means that something unknown went wrong on the server. It can be anything. Your next step is to check your log files.

Comment: This message just appears when you first log in?